# Migrating Oracle forms and report application from 10g to 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms, oraclereports

We have a oracle forms and reports application build in 10g. We are planning to migrate the application to 12c from 10g.

can we simple compile the forms in 12c like we do in 10g ? or we need to re write the complete code again in 12c builder.

If anyone have any article on this, please share the link. That will be really helpful to understand the requirements for migration.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reading [the Oracle Forms documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/formsandreports/install-fnr/upgrade_forms.htm#FRINS422) ?

Comment: Vivek - my company is going through the upgrade of Oracle Forms 10g to 12c. Our codebase is written entirely in PL/SQL. Was your code Java or PL/SQL and did you successfully complete the upgrade to 12c via 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Forms side, you generally only need to recompile your Forms with Forms Designer 12c. There are a few minor changes that you can quickly fix.

On the server side, however, you need to move from Oracle Application Server to WebLogic. Oracle does not document the process for moving directly from Forms 10g to 12c, so it would probably be easiest for you to migrate to 11c first and then to 12c:

1. Follow the instructions in "Fusion Middleware Upgrade Guide for Oracle Portal, Forms, Reports, and Discoverer" (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/upgrade.1111/e10130/toc.htm) to move from Forms 10g to 11c
2. Follow the instructions in "Oracle Fusion Middleware Installing Oracle Forms and Reports," chapter 5 (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/formsandreports/install-fnr/upgrade_forms.htm#FRINS420) to move from Forms 11c to 12c.

Comment: Thanks Sten. It is really helpful